# Creating an anchor in AngularJS ui-grid with paramters

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using the new AngularJS ui-grid in my application. I want to create an anchor that has parameters taken from other fields in the grid as part of the href attribute ie:

```
<a href="/BridgeAssess/nhvrRoute/routeAssessor?routeNo={{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}&journeysId={{grid.routeNo}}&routeVersion={{grid.routeVersion}}" class="create" target="_blank">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</a>
```

This code is stored in an template html file and added to the columDefs object:

```
        $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableSorting: false,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        columnDefs: [
            {field:'link', width: '120'},
            {field:'routeNo', cellTemplate:'templates/cellTemplate.html', width: '120'},
            {field:'routeFrom', displayName:'From', width: '450'},
            {field:'routeTo', displayName: 'To', width: '450'},
            {field:'routeVersion', displayName:'Version', width: '90'},
            {field:'journey', visible: false}
        ]
    };
```

This code creates the link but the only parameter set is routeNo.

I can't see how to set the other parameters. gridOptions.data[rowNum].journey, for example, does not add a value.

How can I get values for the other parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `row.entity.xxx` in your template.

```
<div>
 <a href="test.html?code={{row.entity.code}}&name={{row.entity.name}}&status={{row.entity.status}}">
  Click me
 </a>
</div>
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GspLkfJSonV6IMTmyIm4?p=preview) with more details.